# How soon after getting a 400-class SMTP error will SendMail try connecting to a backup MX record/host?

Tags: linux, centos, email, smtp, sendmail

CentOS | Sendmail 8.14

Hi All,

I couldn't find this in the batbook.  If SendMail attempts to deliver an email to a primary MX record and gets a 400-class error back, how quickly does it try the secondary mx (assuming the secondary record is present)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following in the batbook (page 329):

> The sendmail program then tries to deliver the message to each host in the list of MX
>   hosts, one at a time, until one of them succeeds or until they all fail. The value of an
>   MX record contains a cost value (also called preference) and the hostname to which
>   to connect. All MX hosts at a given cost (preference) are tried before any at a higher
>   cost (lower preference) are tried (that is, all the 5’s are tried, for example, before any
>   6’s). Beginning withV8.8 sendmail, if a host in the list returns a 5xy SMTP code (permanent
>   failure), the effect is to cause subsequent MX hosts to be ignored. (Connect
>   failures are the exception, in that they continue to the next MX host as usual.) Most
>   temporary errors cause sendmail to try the next MX record. If sendmail exhausts the
>   MX list with neither success nor a permanent error, the temporary error will cause
>   the message to be queued for a later attempt.